# Binary data conversion to string

Tags: c#, string, binary-data

I have a chunk of binary data which contains structures with offsets and then strings;
in C++ it is easy:

```
struct foo
{
 int offset;
 char * s;
}

void * data; 
... data is read and set
foo * header = (foo*) data;
header->s = (int)header-> + (int)data;
int len = strlen(header->s);
char* ns = new char[len+1];
strcpy(ns,header->s);
```

simple enough... 
in C# how would you do this?
The biggest problem is that I don't know the length of the string.  It is null terminated.

I have the data in a `byte[]` and an IntPtr to the memory but I need a POINTER to that data a a string (`char *`) something that I can get the length of the string.

Comment: Is it *actually* text data? Or is it just arbitrary binary data, e.g. encrypted data or an image?

Comment: Why doesn't the C++ code just use `std::string`?  Does it need to interoperate with a C library?

Comment: dan04, the c++ is just posted as an example of how he knows it can be done, but he needs that done in C#.  --someone correct me if I'm wrong about that.

Comment: Just convert the byte[] array to a string there is a method for that.  There also is an app for it I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

C# is a high level language, and working with pointers is simply unnatural for this language.

To convert the data from byte array to a string, you can use the `BitConverter` class:

```
BitConverter.ToInt32(byte_array, start index);
```

To convert it to a string, you can use the `StringBuilder` class:

```
StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
// i=starting index of text
for (int i = 3; i<byte_array.Length; i++)
  str.Append(byte_array[i];

return str.ToString();
```

If there is more data after the string, you can put the stopping condition for the loop `byte_array[i]!=0`, and when it stops, `byte_array[i]` will be the string terminator. Save the value of `i`, and you can get the data after it.

Another method of doing this is to use the `ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString()` method:

```
ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(byte_array, start_index, bytes_count);
```

Comment: I could use the stringbuilder class but then looping through each character in the array to see if it is null seems a bit tedious.  as for the asciiencoding, will that work with data that is not ascii?   The reason I ask is that the string has some data encoding hidden in it.  ie if it has a char 0x80, then the next character is a special processed character.  It is a custom format Im parsing so i can't change it.  (Porting old data to a different endian machine).

Comment: In c++, the char type stores ASCII characters, and since you didn't specify any other encoding... Well, in that case you need to find out what encoding you have. I found that the Encoding class has static properties for ASCII, Unicode, UTF32, UTF8, UTF7, BigEndianUnicode. If it's one of these, they all have a GetString() function.

Comment: @vbbartlett 1. Do not use BitConverter for strings; 2. As I understand, you can specify any suitable encoding (which supports your characters, I think UTF8 should be ok), just make sure it's the same on both sides (GetBytes and GetString). It's just the encoding in which your string will be stored in byte_array.